# Make a vertical div with no width selectable

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a layout that has three columns. Each column is split by a vertical div which is dragable (using JavaScript).

The problem is, I want the dragable divs to have no width, but still have a selection width of 5px;

The basic layout looks like this:

```
<div class="col"></div>
   <div class="divide"></div>
<div class="col"></div>
   <div class="divide"></div>
<div class="col"></div>
```

Here is a simplified fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/K4k5W/

You'll notice if you remove the width completely, there's no way to select the div.

I'm guessing this can be solved with a bit of CSS trickery, although I just haven't figured it out yet.

**EDIT** There are elements floated inside each column that need to span the full width. If the divider has a width - there's a gap.

Comment: Why do you want it to have no width? Would making it transparent suffice?

Comment: Unfortunately not, there are elements inside each column that need to span full-width.

Comment: To go along with the previous comment, it would helpful to know why, as there may be another way to solve the problem, for example giving it a width of 5px and a margin of -5px to compensate for the offset.

Comment: I was thinking of offsetting each column using a margin the same width as the divider, however there's then a gap on the other-side

Comment: If you want the divider's out of flow, use `position` (`relative`, `absolute`).

Comment: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/K4k5W/1/) Each divider now has zero width, but the draggable red bit is still 5px.

Comment: thanks dude. Nice work!

Answer (score 0):

hmm. i'm thinking of 2 div's 1 with absolute positioning which u will be using for dragging and the other is the visual one.